# Passing data to CommunityToolkit.Maui Popup

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

How do I pass data to a `CommunityToolkit` `Popup` in a .Net MAUI app?

Documentation shows how to send a result from `Popup` back to the page but doesn’t show how to pass data to the `Popup`.

Comment: A Popup is just a type of Page.  You can pass it data via the constructor, a public property or method, etc

Comment: This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2SEOj0o5j4

Answer (score 4):

I made the following Based on Gerald Versluis video:

toolkit popup Xaml:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           xmlns:model="modelnamespace"
           x:Class="namespace.PopUpSelectService">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="selectService"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:sal_ServiceResponse">
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,auto,auto,auto">
                        <Button Text="{Binding nombre_servicio}"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

PopupSelectService .cs

```
public partial class PopUpSelectService
{ 
    public PopUpSelectService(List<salServiceDTO> sal_Service)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectService.ItemsSource = sal_Service;        
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(((Button)sender).Text);
    }
}
```

How i call the popup In my viewmodel:

```
var popup = new PopUpSelectService(response.sal_Service);                                           
var result = await Shell.Current.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
```

and also in var result you get the value you select on the popup!

Comment: xmlns:model="modelnamespace" ? whats this? from where you have this model?

Comment: @Aakash i get the model from a custom namespace from another project, i didn't put that one in the answer bacause could confuse someone, the model namespace in my case is: xmlns:model="clr-namespace:RipsaWebClient.Shared.Entidades;assembly=RipsaWebClient.Shared"