# How to show a popup from viewmodel. Maui

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I am using Nuget CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views. I my Maui application I also using viewModels. Now I would like to show my custom dialog from viewmodel method. But

```
this.ShowPopup(new DialogPopup());
```

Can by invoke only on Page object.

I can assign value Page to property in my viewModel, but I am not sure this is the best option to implement it:

```
private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel;
public MainPage(MainViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
    _mainViewModel = vm;
    _mainViewModel.Page = this;
}
```

and in view model

```
public Page Page { get; set; }
```

and

```
Page.ShowPopup(new DialogPopup());
```

ShowPopup method look like this:

```
public static void ShowPopup<TPopup>(this Page page, TPopup popup) where TPopup : Popup {...}
```

How should I implement it to be able use this ShowPupup method in my view model?

I am using Net 7.0 and dependency injection to initialize my object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471610/passing-data-to-communitytoolkit-maui-popup/73737949#73737949 this could help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of doing so is described in [this discussion](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/566). You would basically wrap the showing of the popup in a service.

1. Create Interface

```cs
public interface IPopupService
{
    void ShowPopup(Popup popup);
}
```

2. create implementation

```cs
public class PopupService : IPopupService
{
    public void ShowPopup(Popup popup)
    {
        Page page = Application.Current?.MainPage ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
        page.ShowPopup(popup);
    }
}
```

3. Don't forget to register it in your `MauiProgram.cs`

```cs
services.AddTransient<IPopupService, PopupService> ();
```

4. Inject the service into your view model and use it

```cs
    public MainViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
    {
        this.popupService = popupService;
    }

    // and then somewhere (probably in a Command)...
    popupService.ShowPopup(popup);
```

We're also working on adding something like this in the Toolkit itself so that you don't have to write this yourself in your project. You can track the progress of that [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/981).

Comment: We can also show popup like this `Shell.Current.CurrentPage.ShowPopup(popup);`

Comment: If you're using Shell you can indeed also do that!

Answer (score 1):

CommunityToolkit.Maui has inbuild interface to provide logic for Popups.

Create Popup view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           x:Class="YourApp.Views.PopupView"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
           Size="300, 300">
    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />   
        <Button Text="Close" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mct:Popup>
```

--

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

namespace YourApp.Views.Popups;

public partial class PopupView : Popup
{
    public PopupView(PopupViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

Using from other VM:

```
 public OtherViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
 {
     _popupService = popupService;
 }

 public async Task ShowPopup()
 {
     await _popupService.ShowPopupAsync<PopupViewModel>();
 }
```

Register your popup in MauiProgram

```
builder.Services.AddTransientPopup<PopupView,PopupViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

await Shell.Current.CurrentPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please provide password", "OK");